# Does ADO.NET Entity Data Model update with live data ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

net-mvc website which will query an existing database on Azure (I have nothing to do with the database. I just have access to do read only queries.).  I created an ADO.NET Entity Data Model connecting to a Sql Azure Database. This database will be updated everyday with new data. Does the ADO.NET Entity Data Model that i created update itself with live data or is it just a snapshot of the database at the time i created it?

Thanks first time connecting to Azure so not sure if what i'm doing is right.

Comment: It's a snapshot of the DB schema. It doesn't store data in memory or anything.

Comment: Yes, it should continue to retrieve live data. If the schema changes on that database you will get a model mismatch exception and need to revise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entity data model helps requesting data from the DB, it doesn't store data.
Your request will be done against the server data, so you will get up to date data from the DB.

But if the structure of the database changes you will have to recreate the model classes accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So is using the entity data model be worth it in the long run ? There won't be any changes in the near future and if there was it's not a big deal in refreshing the model. Is there a better way in querying data from azure database?